# Echoing Steam avatar using the Steam API

Tags: php, api, echo, steam, avatar

Made a question earlier but it was a bit too vague, I have these pages of code:

steamauth.php:
http://pastebin.com/j7Y3h56i

userInfo.php:
http://pastebin.com/yuv2b8zT

I have a very basic knowledge of PHP, but an advanced knowledge of HTML. What I am looking to do is when a user logs into the site through the steam API, I would like print/echo the steam avatar of the user. I tried using

```
 <img src=<?php echo '"{$avatar}"'; ?> />
```

in the index.php as well as other variations, but nothing seems to work. What line of code can I use to echo the steam avatar, and where does it go?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use:

```
<img src=<?php echo('"' . $avatar . '"'); ?></img>
```

And make sure that your URL starts with http://
to check just use:

```
<php echo($avatar); ?>
```

you always could use:

```
<img src=<?php echo('"http://' . $avatar . '"'); ?></img>
```

And NEVER forget:
first load your functions/variables before they are usable :p

Comment: Its throwing me an error saying that variable avatar is undefined? Also I am previewing this on a local server so there is no http.

Comment: could you put it in pastebin or something?
the code block
(from <?php to ?> or <script> to </script>)

Comment: i dont see a way how you parse the data from the player to the index documents itselves. ill fix that for you if you have a minute

Comment: If you would that could be absolutely amazing :D

Comment: it could return errors because i didnt test it but i think it will do it :)

Comment: You got a typo in there `eco` (twice)

Comment: i did fix it in the pastebin file :) its my fault